# how to test children function from component jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the below react component which calls the `<ChildComp>` component and has prop functions.

```
const MyComp = (props) => {
    return (
       <div>
          <ChildComp
              beforeRender={()=>{
                 console.log("Before Render");
              }}
              afterRender={()=>{
                 console.log("After Render");
              }}
          />
       </div>
   );
};
```

Here is my test so far

```
test(`MyComp`, () => {
        const tree = renderer
            .create(<MyComp></Icon>)
            .toJSON();
    });
```

What is the best way to test that i have called beforeRender and afterRender in jest?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should look into enzyme shallow rendering (https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html).

You can then use the find method (https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html) to grab the Child component and access its props and assert they have been called.